# How to rotate (x, y) for grid snapping

Tags: c#, wpf, math, geometry, 2d

I've made grid snapping for normal square grid based on what I assume is a popular method for doing so

```
int newX = Math.Round(oldX / gridCubeWidth)  * gridCubeWidth;
int newY = Math.Round(oldY / gridCubeHeight) * gridCubeHeight;
```

what wasn't intuitive to me is that this doesn't work with my diagonal grid.

[image]

I highlighted a red rectangle for the pattern my object would take if moved around, leaving the purple circle unreachable.
What I need is to rotate this calculation 45 degrees so it matches the example below it, thus allowing me to snap the object correctly aligned with the diagonal grid.

Comment: How are you creating the grid? It seems to have angles different from 45 deg. Maybe 60 deg? Can you show the code for the grid creation?

Comment: The row pattern is alternating whereas your code assumes that consecutive rows are identical, as they would be in a normal square grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the diagonal grid form a different perspective. It is a superposition of 2 regular grids offset by half the grid size, shown below as blue and green grids (the green vertical lines match the left and right borders).

[image]

So I suggest to find the snapping point in the two grids and to take the closest one.

```
const int SubgridWidth = 40, SubgridHeight = 28;

double newX1 = Snap(oldX, SubgridWidth);
double newY1 = Snap(oldY, SubgridHeight);

double newX2 = SnapShifted(oldX, SubgridWidth);
double newY2 = SnapShifted(oldY, SubgridHeight);

double squareDist1 = SquareDist(oldX, oldY, newX1, newY1);
double squareDist2 = SquareDist(oldX, oldY, newX2, newY2);

if (squareDist1 < squareDist2) {
    // Snap to (newX1, newY1).
} else {
    // Snap to (newX2, newY2).
}

double Snap(double x, double gridSize)
{
    return Math.Round(x / gridSize) * gridSize;
}

double SnapShifted(double x, double gridSize)
{
    return (Math.Round(x / gridSize - 0.5) + 0.5) * gridSize;
}

double SquareDist(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;
    return dx * dx + dy * dy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is no 45-degree angles at your picture.

But for any angles calculation is simple using spacing between grid nodes in vertical and horizontal directions.  At first - round coordinates down - to the left bottom corner, then shift them to the center of the cell.

```
 int newX = (Math.Floor(oldX / HorizontalSpacing) + 0.5) * HorizontalSpacing;
 int newY = (Math.Floor(oldY / VerticalSpacing)  + 0.5) * VerticalSpacing;
```